# How to use ES6 destructuring assignment to assign one object to another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I need the value of keys in object `arrA` to be copied from `arrB` based on `key` name. Here are my two objects:

```
let arrA = {
    'aaa':'',
    'bbb':'',
    'ccc':''
}
let arrb = {
    'aaa':'111',
    'bbb':'222',
    'ccc':'333',
    'ddd':'444',
    'eee':'555',
    ...
}
```

How do I do this with the `ES6` deconstructive assignment:

```
arrA = {
    'aaa':'111',
    'bbb':'222',
    'ccc':'333'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you'd have to explicitly define each property you'd want to copy:

```js
let arra = {
  'aaa': '',
  'bbb': '',
  'ccc': ''
};
let arrb = {
  'aaa': '111',
  'bbb': '222',
  'ccc': '333',
  'ddd': '444',
  'eee': '555',
};

({aaa: arra.aaa, bbb: arra.bbb, ccc: arra.ccc} = arrb);

console.log(arra);
```

However, this code is very repetitive, and the worst part is that it's explicit with what gets copied.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of destructuring is to pull out variables from the object into your local scope. Learn more about destructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You're probably better off solving this problem with different tools.

Using a combination of different functions, you can do this instead:

```js
let arra = {
    'aaa':'',
    'bbb':'',
    'ccc':''
}
let arrb = {
    'aaa':'111',
    'bbb':'222',
    'ccc':'333',
    'ddd':'444',
    'eee':'555'
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(arra)
    .map(key => [key, arrb[key]])
)

console.log(result)
```

First, I'm grabbing all of the keys from arra with [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), then I'm creating a list of pairs using the [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, and finally I'm turning the pairs into a new object with [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 0):

[Lodash's `pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) is your friend here (because life is too short to write boring boilerpllate code):

You just `npm install lodash` and say:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

_.pick( sourceObjectOrArray, arrayOfDesiredPaths );
```

Like this:

```
const _      = require('lodash');
const source = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
  f: 6,
  g: 7,
}
const picked = _.pick( source, ['a','c','e'] );

console.log( JSON.stringify(picked) );
```

And you'll find `picked` is what you'd expect:

```
{
  a: 1,
  c: 3,
  e: 5
}
```